# does deleteMany triggers remove post middleware on all deleted documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

in my application, I need to remove all references in the MongoDB database in order to prevent any crashes in the future. therefore I have written a post remove middleware in my mongoose schema. But my question in that if I delete many documents using deleteMany, does it call remove post middleware on each deleted document, or do I need to implement deleteMany post middleware?

Answer (score 0):

It won't trigger, in order to invoke a `post` function after a `updateMany` or `removeMany` you need to use the following [syntax](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-post):

```
schema.post(/Many$/, function(res) {
  console.log('this fired after you ran `updateMany()` or `deleteMany()`);
});
```